# Javascript DOMParser

Tags: javascript, for-loop, domparser

I have difficult time to loop through an xmlDoc, any help would appreciate. Here's my original html

```
<ul class="overview">
    <li class="item first odd">Li content 1</li>
    <li class="item even">li content 2</li>
     ......
     //I have a total of 16 LIs in here
    <li class="item last even">li content last 16</li>        
</ul>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
<script>
    var myHtmlContent = jQuery( "ul.overview" ).html();
    var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myHtmlContent , "text/html");
    var root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName ("li");
    var len = root.length;
    alert(len); // I get the right number  
    if( len > 8 ) { 
      for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var myCurrentLiContent = root[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
        alert(myCurrentLiContent ); 
        /*
        My goal is to get the whole text like this "<li class="item 
        first odd">Li content 1</li>" so I can mannualy render later on, 
        but I get nothing from  myCurrentLiContent variable... 
        So please help.
        */
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When the len is 8 or less, the `if(len > 8)` evaluates to false and don't execute your for-loop. Just in case, when the len is 9 and more. Did you try to log something after the if and before the for-loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask], before posting your next question here. You've not explained a problem or asked a question.

Comment: Yes Steven, I did log and I have a total of 16 LIs in my ul.

Comment: In that case, it should work... did you prevent continuous dialogs by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You got the len equal to 3 but than you're checking if the len is greater than 8. It is not, so your code does not execute. Remove the if statement and the code wil work fine.

Comment: As you can see, the `......` is a placeholder. But i think, he expects the len to be 8 and therefore he needs the greater-or-equal operator `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="overview">
...
var myHtmlContent = jQuery( "ul.overview" ).html();
```

in this case, `myHtmlContent` is a list, not a node. Make this `id="overview"` and `jQuery('ul#overview')` to (probably) fix this. It's best to diagnose these with a debugger with variable watchers, or at least generous `console.log()` statements, rather than to try to dissect it from a complete blob later.

Answer (score 0):

Ah!! I found a solution that works for me. 
Instead of this

```
<script>     
   ....
  var myCurrentLiContent = root[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue, 
  ....
</script>
```

All I have to do is this

```
<script>
    .... 
    var myCurrentLiContent = root[i].innerHtml
    ....
</script>
```

Thank you for all of your helps, and the are all valueable to me.
Thanks!!!